# Unable to Install more Apps in Micromax Unite 2

Tags: applications, internal-storage, insufficient-memory, app2sd, internal-sd

I have Micromax Unite 2, in which 1GB RAM, 1GB Phone Storage, 8 GB Internal SD Card.
I have just installed few apps like whatsapp, facebook, skype and Microsoft Lync. After installed these apps, phone storage full around 90%, there's left 100MB space and no more app able to install hence i bought 16GB External SD card and set it default storage in Setting but after this, i am still getting same issue.
I have tried to move app but there's just skype able to move in Ext SD Card.

I just want to know that if phone storage has been full then app should install in internal or external card but that's not happening....

so please tell me anyone that it's Micromax Unite 2 drawback or it's just issue in my phone.

Answer (score 0):

Neither.  A lot of Android apps simply don't support being moved to the internal or external SD card.

If you are rooted, you could use an so like [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) to forcibly move some of them, although some may not work if you do this.